# Converting TSQL to Postgresql - SQL Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "["

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration

I am trying to convert TSQL to PostgreSQL

A script is as following,

```
select v.ASSET_NUM, v.SERIAL_NUM, xm.NAME, xm.*
from [SiebelDB].[dbo].[S_ASSET] v (nolock) 
inner join [SiebelDB].[dbo].[S_ASSET_XM] xm (nolock) on xm.PAR_ROW_ID = v.ROW_ID
where 
xm.TYPE = 'Service Plan'
and xm.NAME like 'G3%'
```

and I receive an error say as,  syntax error at or near "["
Position: 54

Any help?

Comment: Don't tag SQL Server when your desired result is PostgreSQL - you want experts in PostgreSQL.

Comment: [Bad habits: putting nolock everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Is this really Postgresql? `dbo` and `(nolock)` are a Sql Server things (and you shouldn't use `nolock` like this anyway). But if it is Postgresql, that database dose not use square brackets to mark object names.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn OP is wanting to convert from SQL Server, but doesn't appear to have started the conversion yet.

Comment: Tip: Start with cleaning up the code still in SQL Server. E.g. remove `(nolock)`, switch to ANSI SQL complaint delimiters `"S_ASSET"`, etc. Verify it still works. Then move to Postgresql.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql does not use the `[]` characters to mark out object names. Nor does it treat schemas the same way. Finally, it doesn't have the same hinting mechanisms (and you shouldn't have used `nolock` like that in Sql Server in the first place, anway).

The closest I can get for Postgresql would **tend to** look like this:

```
select v.ASSET_NUM, v.SERIAL_NUM, xm.NAME, xm.*
from S_ASSET v  
inner join S_ASSET_XM xm on xm.PAR_ROW_ID = v.ROW_ID
where xm.TYPE = 'Service Plan'
    and xm.NAME like 'G3%';
```

Where the database and any schema contexts are determined by the connection properties. I say, "tend to" because I can't know for sure how your postgresql tables are setup compared to Sql Server.

Comment: Postgres uses schemas in pretty much the same way as SQL Server does. The way both treat _databases_ are different though.